# The Specified network name is no longer available

Tags: windows, networking

I have an application the uses a shared drive drive to access some data it uses.  I currently have about 100 people using the application fine but it will not allow new connection.

I can not access the share via UNC either typing the IP or the server name.  I can ping the server name and IP though.

A restart will fix this but not ideal during working hours.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me as through your application might be keeping connections persistently open rather than only opening a connection when required and closing them when done.  You're likely getting some high resource utilisation on the server in question too.

You can check this in Computer Management under Shared Folders | Sessions or Open Files.

In general, Windows file sharing is not suitable for this kind of use, and you should probably be looking to implement a proper database.